# Is FFXV's LOD system similar to Unreal Nanite's LOD system?

Tags: textures, graphics, level-of-detail

I was reading [this article](https://www.modmy.com/hidden-settings-final-fantasy-xvs-benchmark-force-lower-and-low-graphics-and-extra-performance) and it seems the LOD system in FFXV is similar in that the texture is not swapped, but the number of polygons changes depending on the distance. Is Nanite the same, or is it way more advanced than the FFXV LOD system? If so, in what ways?

Comment: This just describes what all level of detail systems do. I don't see anything in the article that suggests this is particularly similar to Nanite's virtualized geometry approach — can you clarify what's making you associate this with Nanite specifically? There are existing articles and videos explaining Nanite's technique in more detail than we could easily go into in an answer here, so I think you'd find your curiosity better-satisfied elsewhere.

Comment: Well, it seems like it doesn't require a new model and new texture to be loaded in like Nanite, that's why I asked the question. I am wondering if what are the differences between the two approaches.

Comment: What in the article suggests that the model is not loaded in? Re-using the same texture between LoDs is not unique to Nanite.